# What switch would replace a series of 6 pins linked by jumpers?

Tags: switches, function-generator, jumper

I've bought a small electronics kit - a function generator which produces a 1kHz signal in various waveshapes - square, sine, triangle and integrator. It's a basic kit on a single PCB (555 timer based) and you select the waveform you want using a jumper between 4 pairs of pins.

I would like to put this kit in a small box to use as a more robust tool for testing equipment. I need a chassis mounted switch which could essentially imitate the action of moving a jumper between these four sets of pins. What sort of switch would I need, and how would I wire it?

Comment: 4 pairs of pins is 8, not 6. Schematic? Failing that, are one side of the pins (as I would expect) tied together?

Comment: Depending on the actual circuit, a 1P4T slide switch might work.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, you're right, it's 8 pins. And one side are all tied together. I found it weirdly difficult to source a 1P4T slide but I did find a spare 3P4T in my components box which I can use one pole of for the same effect. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bit hard to answer without a schematic, but a [rotary switch](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/switches/rotary-switches/200) is a typical solution. You can get them in many different configurations. For example, a four position double pole switch as shown below.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If one side of each jumper is tied to a common node, then you just need a single-pole rotary switch.

Otherwise, you'll need a set of interlocked pushbuttons — the kind where when you push one in, the others pop out. Or you could use an N-pole rotary switch, one pole for each of the original jumpers.